# Automatic weight painting failed to paint mesh correctly

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, rigify, append

I've replaced a mesh that was previously animated with an improved mesh. No custom weight paints were used on the previous mesh. Unlike the previous mesh, I appended the improved mesh without the rig from the original project. The improved mesh works correctly with the original rig, but does not weight paint correctly with the appended version of the rig. The weight paints of some bones are magenta (hot pink) while the rest are blue. Scale and rotation have been applied. The only notable problem I know of is the parenting problem, which causes incorrect object coordinates. Applying location doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: Can you add a blend file showing the problem? ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))  It's difficult to diagnose weight paint problems otherwise.  Also, be aware that automatic weight painting is fragile and often needs manual adjustment afterwards.

Comment: I cannot unfortunately, since I get the error when uploading: 'There was an internal error attempting to complete your request.' Can I add a picture instead?